# JQuery - Continuous animation on Mouse Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a kind of menu system with a custom scroll bar but I want to have it continuous so that if someone holds the up or down buttons it will continuously scroll until they release the mouse.

I was thinking of trying a timer so that it scrolls by so many pixels every split second but if there was a way to do this to make it less jumpy, that would be great.

```js
$("#up_arrow").bind("mousedown", function(){
  var current_position = parseInt($("#scroll").scrollTop());
  $("#scroll").scrollTop(current_position - 100);
});

$("#down_arrow").bind("mousedown", function(){
  var current_position = parseInt($("#scroll").scrollTop());
  $("#scroll").scrollTop(current_position + 100);
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:150px;
}
#scroll{
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><center><button id="up_arrow">Up</button></center></li>
<li>
  <ul id="scroll">
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><center><button id="down_arrow">Down</button></center></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you looked at using CSS transitions and animations? It would give you the smoothest possible scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my JS to the following and got the result I was looking for:

```js
var timeoutId1 = 0;
var timeoutId2 = 0;

$('#up_arrow').on('mousedown', function() {
    scrollup();
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId1);
});

$('#down_arrow').on('mousedown', function() {
    scrolldown();
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId2);
});

function scrollup(){
 var current_position = parseInt($("#scroll").scrollTop());
  $("#scroll").scrollTop(current_position - 100);
  timeoutId1 = setTimeout(function(){scrollup()} , 300);
}

function scrolldown(){
 var current_position = parseInt($("#scroll").scrollTop());
  $("#scroll").scrollTop(current_position + 100);
  timeoutId2 = setTimeout(function(){scrolldown()} , 300);
}
```

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  width:150px;
}
#scroll{
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><center><button id="up_arrow">Up</button></center></li>
<li>
  <ul id="scroll">
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00"></li>
  <li><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff"></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><center><button id="down_arrow">Down</button></center></li>
</ul>
```